# console.writeline vs console.write

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I just realized that when I write code below it did not work. (It did not write anything on VS output window)

```
float myval = 0.2f;
Console.Write( "MyValue: " + myval);
```

But then I tried this and It worked.

```
 float myval = 0.2f;
 Console.WriteLine( "MyValue: " + myval);
```

As far as I know, the only difference between `Console.Write` and `Console.WriteLine` is one of them just writes on new lines.
So, am I missing anything ? Why my first code did not work?

Comment: Did it write anything to the console? Perhaps the Output window can only write whole lines?

Comment: @canton7 yes It writes other logs.

Comment: The console output is probably buffered and most likely won't print anything until a newline is printed, the stream is flushed, or the program ends.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp The console is not, but the VS output window is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Johnny Mopp and @Joel Coehoorn .

VS output window is probably buffered and most likely won't print anything until a newline is printed, the stream is flushed, or the program ends.

I tried this and It worked

```
float myval = 0.2f;
Console.Write( "Console.Write => MyValue: " + myval);
Console.WriteLine( "Console.WriteLine => MyValue: " + myval);
```

Ps: I am still confused about why it did not worked with other logs. (there are some other logs in my program and VS output window shows all of them except my `Console.Write` )